# Sum of index space :: T-SQL vs GUI

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have recently rebuilt all indexes on a table and the GUI from SSMS tells me that the index space is 7 555.711 MB.

[image]

But if I look at the actual index space through T-SQL I have a different result:

```
SELECT tn.[name] AS [Table name], ix.[name] AS [Index name],
SUM(sz.[used_page_count]) * 8 * 1024/(1024 * 1024)  AS [Index size (MB)]
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS sz
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS ix ON sz.[object_id] = ix.[object_id] 
AND sz.[index_id] = ix.[index_id]
INNER JOIN sys.tables tn ON tn.OBJECT_ID = ix.object_id
where tn.[name] = 'MyTableName'
GROUP BY tn.[name], ix.[name]
ORDER BY tn.[name]
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: Because your definition of "index" includes the clustered index, which Management Studio considers to be "data" (which isn't wrong -- the clustered index *is* the table data). 3970 + 7555 ~= 1452 + 1590 + 1590 + 1452 + 1452 + 3987. You can distinguish the clustered index/heap structure by checking the `index_id`, 0 is heap and 1 is the clustered index. Anything above 1 is an "index" index.

Comment: As an FYI, [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea86c46b6bd62b7d117d067095a2fb7c) is the query SSMS uses to calculate Index Space (Parameters declared at the start).

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jeroen Mostert,

In fact the cluster index is part of the table data.

With Index Space SSMS is calculating only the non-clustered index which are:
1452 + 1590 + 1590 + 1452 + 1452 = **7536MB**

which is very close to **7555MB**